# Why does it take longer to run a query in Python than it does in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: python, pandas, oracle

Edit: VS Code doesn't play nice. I ran the exact same code in Jupyter and it worked, and faster.

I'm stuck using 32 bit Python because the database is 32bit. I don't know if that affects the query's speed, but it does give memory issues so I thought I'd mention it here.

I've noticed that when running a query in Oracle SQL Developer it goes 20%-30% faster than when I connect to the database through python and run my query. I'm using pandas to export the results to csv as part of an automated process, otherwise I'd manually export it from Oracle.

```
import cx_Oracle as cx
import pandas as pd


dsn_tns = cx.makedsn('server_name', 'port', service_name='service_name')
conn = cx.connect(user=config.username, password=config.password, dsn=dsn_tns)
cursor = conn.cursor()

f = open('.sql file path', 'r')
sql = f.read()
f.close()

pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
```

This is simple, it works, but it is much slower than just running my query in Oracle.

My question is, why? And how can I improve the speed?

Comment: What does 20-30% translate to in terms of elapsed time?  The code you posted includes making a connection to the database.  Is that included in your SQL Developer test?  I'm assuming your Python code is running on the same machine that SQL Developer is.  How much data are you retrieving from the database server?  You may want to adjust the `arraysize` https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuningfetch

Comment: 20-30% is my guestimate. From the last run Oracle said about 800 seconds, and Python came in at 1300 seconds. But it varies. I'm reading directly from a .sql file that has the query on it. There are actually a few I'm looping over. The data ranges from 100MB to 300MB

Comment: There are 80-95 columns depending the query. I've noticed from a memory error that it's trying to load an array size **(10, 1859362)** what's that about? I don't think I understand what that's telling me. Sorry, I know that's a separate question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure what that memory error is all about.  My first thought would be to experiment with the `arraysize`.  Decreasing it should decrease the memory used.  Increasing it will probably result in faster execution (assuming that you can give it the memory it needs).

Comment: The "bitness" of the Oracle client is independent from database bitness. BTW, how do you manage to run a 32-bit Oracle database in 2021?

Comment: Are you sure SQL Developer is fetching all rows, or is it just getting a few pages worth?

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the various comments:

- check you are measuring the same things in both places.  Are you running on the same machine? Are you measuring connection times and SQL file loading times? Is SQL Developer actually fetching all rows, or just some page(s) - this is a common gotcha I've seen.
- Follow the cx_Oracle tuning tips in the manual: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html

Answer (score 0):

VS Code was giving me the issue. I used Jupyter and it worked just fine, and quicker too.